# How to Transfer a zip file into ubuntu server?

Tags: 14.04, scp

I have `d:/upload/jboss-eap-6.2.0.zip`

This file need to uploaded into Ubuntu server

I tried with following command

```
scp d:/upload/jboss-eap-6.2.0.zip ubuntu@ip-10-47-175-216:/home/ubuntu
```

Comment: what Os you are using windows or ubuntu ?

Comment: i am using putty in windows pc

Comment: you are connected via ssh to ubuntu ?

Comment: Yes i using SSH

Comment: What happened when you tried to SCP?

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname d: Name or service not known

Comment: Install winscp on Windows ;)

Comment: its already installed, through that i have opened the Putty

Comment: @IRAP that's not how this works. You open winscp from windows and connect to Ubuntu and then copy the file over from within winscp. Putty has no place in there. Nor can you open putty from winscp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution:

create one folder as "putty" in program files folder, and download and paste the 'putty and pscp' exe file in to putty folder

then set the path from windows cmd : set PATH=C:\Program Files\putty;%PATH%

then in cmd> pscp -i d:/key/xxx.ppk d:/upload/jboss-eap-6.2.0.zip  ubuntu@xxxxx.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu

-i is Private key for Authentication
.ppk - generated from Puttygen (from .pem file)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've `ssh`ed in to the remote computer and you're trying to `scp` from a local file. That won't work. The remote shell session has no concept of your local filesystem.

You need to push the file from something running in Windows. WinSCP is a good client. You feed it your SSH details and it'll give you decent enough file access on the remote server. Or you can use a SFTP (like Filezilla) client, again working over SSH.

Answer (score 1):

In windows machine open cmd :

```
 set PATH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY
```

Then from cmd also try this command:

```
pscp d:/upload/jboss-eap-6.2.0.zip  ubuntu@your-ip:/home/ubuntu/
```

Your ip like : `10.1.1.1`

Comment: i am getting this error: d:/upload/jboss-eap-6.2.0.zip: No such file or directory
. but i have zip in this location only

Comment: use this command from cmd not from putty

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aMy9I.png

Comment: please check the image screenshot, i am using in command

Comment: man close putty and try it from cmd in windows

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mTgBB.png

Comment: i tried in cmd windows

Comment: write this code before it :  set PATH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY

Comment: @IRAP is it ok now  ?

Comment: No, i try its not set.

Comment: Hi nux, thanks for you tips. i found the solution how to do it.

Comment: LoL this conversation up here. nux was so patient, kudos to him :D